# How to route to a Different URL using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to know if it is possible to index route to a different URL.

Currently, when i type localhost, it Redirect to localhost (obvious)

However, i wish to redirect it directly to  localhost/meals.

Here is my current Code Snippet:

```
var Index = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                <IndexRoute component={WeekMenu}/>
                <Route path="meals" component={WeekMenu}/>
            <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
            </Route>
    </Router>
```

Well, by default when i got to "localhost" it does redirect me to the "meals" since my index route is redirectin to "WeekMenu" thats the same component i call for "meals".

But the URL remains the same i.e "localhost"

Can react router change the URL too "localhost/meals"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IndexRedirect` for that:

```
<Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
            <IndexRedirect to="/meals" />
            <Route path="meals" component={WeekMenu}/>
            <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
        </Route>
</Router>
```

This automatically redirects visitor to `/meals` page if he visits `/`.

See [React documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md) for additional information